# Why is the first item of an int array type casted to an int?

Tags: solidity, arrays, data-types

I was reading a book on solidity, the array was defined as 
`int[5] age= [int(10),20,30,40,50]`

When data type int was declared at the start then why it is declared again in the array with 10?

Answer (score 3):

Solidity determines the type of array literal (`[int(10),20,30,40,50]`) as the smallest type all the elements could be implicitly converted into.  Here element types are: `int`, `uint8`, `uint8`, `uint8`, `uint8`, so the smallest type all elements may could be converted into is `int`.  So the type of array literal is `int[5]`.

If you omit `int(...)`, then types of all the elements would be `uint8`, thus the whole literal would have type `uint8[5]` which is incompatible with the type of the variable this value is about to be assigned to.

See [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.6/types.html#array-literals) for details.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of declaring data type before array name? Like in this case ` int[5]` so what will this int do?

Comment: `int[5]` is the type of the variable `age`, not the type of the expression to the right from the equals sign.  The type of an expression is determined by the expression itself and should be compatible with the type of a variable the value of this expression is being assigned to.